# FQL: Filter to items containing a space

Tags: pnp-search-webparts, fql

We're attempting to create a video portal in Sharepoint, using the PnP Search Webparts as the main interface. We've encountered an issue where many of the videos have unintelligible titles - like 405F537B-BC55-461A-9DC8-144CA2CBBC4C.

To work around this, we'd like to only include videos which contain a space in the title, or %20 in the file name, in the search results.

The PnP search results web part allows us to refine the results using FQL, and I've tried various ways to display results that contain a space in the title or name to no avail; such as:

```
title:" "
title:*" "*
title: string("* *", mode="phrase")
name: string("%20", mode="phrase")
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try title:NOT "* *"

Comment: Thanks, @Christoffer, however we're trying to exclude items which do not have a space in the title, rather than exclude items which do! Either way, neither `title:NOT"* *"` nor `title:"* *"` return any results...